# Cloud Tasks with an automatically scaling App Engine that last longer than 10 minutes

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-tasks

I have a backend for an iOS app that I've built on App Engine and I'm looking to do potentially long running background tasks to add records to my Cloud SQL database. Is this possible without Compute Engine? I've seen Cloud Tasks can do asynchronous work and you can set the dispatchDeadline to basically anything you want, but I've also read in the documentation

*For App Engine tasks, 0 indicates that the request has the default deadline. The default deadline depends on the scaling type of the service: 10 minutes for standard apps with automatic scaling, 24 hours for standard apps with manual and basic scaling, and 60 minutes for flex apps. If the request deadline is set, it must be in the interval [15 seconds, 24 hours 15 seconds]. Regardless of the task's dispatchDeadline, the app handler will not run for longer than than the service's timeout. **We recommend setting the dispatchDeadline to at most a few seconds more than the app handler's timeout**. For more information see Timeouts.*

I don't particularly need the App Engine instance to care if the task completes or not... so I'm not sure why the recommendation is **at most a few seconds more than the app handler's timeout** ... can anyone shed any light on this? What am I missing? Adding a Compute Engine for these relatively simple tasks that will take at most a few ours to complete seems like a lot of overhead and I don't want this to dictate which scaling options I choose.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommendation is only for logging purpose. If your task timeout is shorter that your app timeout, you never know if there is an error from  your app, because you don't have the return.

If you have longer timeout on Cloud Task, you can catch and trace in Cloud Task logs the app return code and thus gracefully track the errors.

App Engine with a [basic scaling mode](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/config/appref#scaling_elements) is a great solution.

1. You have [9H free per days (B instance type)](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#free-tier-usage-limits)
2. App Engine scale to 0 automatically after a period of inactivity (that you can define in the basic scaling: `idle_timeout` parameter)
3. You have a regional available service. Not a zonal like a compute engine, or you need to have 9 computes engine, to cover the regional High Availability (3 per zone, over 3 zones)
4. You don't have server to manage: no update, no patching, no network/ip/firewall rule...

If you ask me about the overhead, I will anser Compute Engine and not App Engine (even if you need few configuration)

Comment: Thanks Guillaume... So, to be clear, if I have a Cloud Task that has a longer timeout than 10 minutes on automatic scaling App engine, it will still run, but I will have to manage the success of it on my own through logs, because I will hear nothing back from App Engine. Correct?

Comment: After the 10 minutes, it's "serverless". Your App Engine instance can continue to live or Google Cloud platform can choose to evict it if there is no activity (no new request) on it.

Comment: But the Cloud Task will still continue to run?

Comment: Please forgive my ignorance I'm very new to GCP

Comment: No problem, everyone needs to start a day, and serverless is a new paradigm. In short: Cloud Task run a request and wait up to the timeout (App Engine endpoint are special for Cloud Task, the legacy where [Task Queue where a part of App Engine service](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/taskqueue)). I don't know how it runs, where and on what, it's serverless. But, in case of error, you can configure retry on Cloud Task.

Comment: Serverless Product, like Cloud Functions, Cloud Run and App Engine, you pay for the CPU that you use when you process a request. If there is not request being processed, you should not perform processing (you can understand that background processing are impossible). CPU and Memory have cost for GCP. If there is no request processed, GCP doesn't bill you, and it can choose to delete the instance to attribute the CPU and memory to an active instance, which will be billed to earn money. Do you feel the principle?

Comment: Thanks a lot Guillaume :) I'll try my best